# In VBA how do I populate an array of type Long and pass to a function to populate cell in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have just started to learn VBA to write a function to work with my Excel spreadsheet.
I am using Windows 11, Excel Version 2306 and VBA version 7.1

I have hunted all over to find answers to my problem but even when I try exactly what they say it doesn't work.  I must be missing something.

I am creating an array of numbers using the type Long.  I populate that array and then pass it to another function to manipulate the array.  I have written some basic code to see how it works before adding details.

I trigger a macro when a cell in a certain range changes.
That macro creates and populates the array and then passes it to a function. The array seems to be working inside the macro after being populated because I display a message.  But passing it to the function causes problems.  I have tried creating, populating and passing the array in different ways but nothing works.  I include my code below where you can see the different things I have tried.  I comment out the first Worksheet_Change macro to run the second one which creates, populates and passes the array in another way.

In the first case I get an error that the TesetArrayOne function causes a compile error Sub or Function not defined.  In the second case in AccumulationMacroTwo I get a compile error ByRef argument type mismatch.

```
'I comment this code out to run the second one below
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
  
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K2:K84")) Is Nothing Then
    Call AccumulationMacroOne
  End If

End Sub

Sub AccumulationMacroOne()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim kRange As String
    Dim kString As String
    kString = "K"

    Dim AccumulationArray() As Variant
    AccumulationArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    
    MsgBox "Array 2 =  " & AccumulationArray(2) & " count is " & UBound(AccumulationArray) + 1

    For iRow = 2 To 84
         kRange = kString & iRow
        
         If Range(kRange).Value <> "" Then
            Call TestArrayOne(AccumulationArray)
        End If
    Next iRow

End Sub

'Compile Error Sub or Function not defined and AccumulationArray(2) is underlined
Function TestArrayOne(ByRef AccmulationArray As Variant)

MsgBox "array 2 = " & AccumulationArray(2)
   
    If IsArray(AccumulationArray) Then
        MsgBox "It is an array"
    Else
        MsgBox "NOT an array"
    End If
    
    If UBound(AccumulationArray) + 1 > 6 Then
        MsgBox "size is > 6"
    Else
        MsgBox "size is < 6"
    End If

    If AccumulationArray(2) = 2 Then
        MsgBox "Array(2) is 2"
    Else
        MsgBox "Array(2) is NOT 2"
    End If
   
End Function

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
  
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K2:K84")) Is Nothing Then
    Call AccumulationMacroTwo
  End If

End Sub

'Compile Error ByRef argument type mismatch with AccumulationArray in the Call TestArrayTwo is highlighted
Sub AccumulationMacroTwo()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim kRange As String
    Dim kString As String
    kString = "K"

    Dim AccumulationArray(1 To 6) As Long
    AccumulationArray(1) = 1
    AccumulationArray(2) = 2
    AccumulationArray(3) = 3
    AccumulationArray(4) = 4
    AccumulationArray(5) = 5
    AccumulationArray(6) = 6
    
    
    MsgBox "AccumulationMacroTwo Array 2 =  " & AccumulationArray(2) & " count is " & UBound(AccumulationArray)

    For iRow = 2 To 84
         kRange = kString & iRow
        
         If Range(kRange).Value <> "" Then
            Call TestArrayTwo(AccumulationArray)
        End If
    Next iRow

End Sub


Function TestArrayTwo(ByRef AccmulationArray As Long)

MsgBox "TestArrayTwo array 2 = " & AccumulationArray(2)
   
    If IsArray(AccumulationArray) Then
        MsgBox "It is an array"
    Else
        MsgBox "NOT an array"
    End If
    
    If UBound(AccumulationArray) + 1 > 6 Then
        MsgBox "size is > 6"
    Else
        MsgBox "size is < 6"
    End If

    If AccumulationArray(2) = 2 Then
        MsgBox "Array(2) is 2"
    Else
        MsgBox "Array(2) is NOT 2"
    End If
   
End Function
```

Comment: There is a typo in the argument of TestArrayOne: AccmulationArray. The argument is an array, you need parenthesis "AccumulationArray() As". I would put "Option Explicit" in the first line of the module to check for typo's

Comment: Just typos! In the signature of both functions, there is `AccmulationArray` (the `u` after `cc` is missing) yet in the rest of the functions, there is `AccumulationArray`.

Comment: The typo is shameful.  Definitely time to upgrade my computer glasses.  The letters are merging together.  Thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Hennep's comment: both errors are due to your functions expecting a single value instead of array. In VBA, when declaring an array it is denoted by the () (e.g. Dim arr() As Integer).

When passing an array to a function, it follows the same declaration rules. The fixed lines for your code:

```
Function TestArrayOne(ByRef AccumulationArray() As Variant)
Function TestArrayTwo(ByRef AccumulationArray() As Long)
```

Edit: Fixed second typo and adding Thomas's comment that you can use Variant in both cases. I assume you thought the type may have been the source of the error, so hopefully that clarifies.

Comment: And TestArrayTwo has the same typo, "AccmulationArray". Later in the function "AccumulationArray" is used, which is an undeclared variable at that point.

Comment: Note that you can use  `ByRef AccumulationArray As Variant` in both cases as a Variant  can be anything (including an Array of Variant or an Array of Long).

Comment: Sometimes you want a Variant type because a value can be Null. For testing @Lorna_from_Perth is using numbers now, but we don't know what else she will do with her code.